# How to retrieve a node by label in a "grim" graph?

Tags: nim-lang

I'd like to use the [grim](https://github.com/ebran/grim) library to create and traverse graphs, but I don't understand how to access a graph having the label in a string.

```py
import  grim
import sequtils


var g = newGraph("my graph")

let node = g.addNode("F4", %(Id: "none", desc: "OK"))
let dest = g.addNode("F8", %(Id: "dest"))

# get node knowing label?
let label1 = "F4"
echo g.node(label1)  # <--- this does not work:
```

This script returns:

```
unhandled exception: key not found: F4 [KeyError]
```

Can you tell me how to access a node having the label?

In my graph each label is unique, but it's not granted by the library so that can be the issue, so maybe I'm looking for a better attribute to use to uniquely identify a node.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library inserts the nodes with an [oid](https://nim-lang.org/docs/oids.html). If you add a node without `oid`, it gets automatically generated, and it will be the index to look for in `g.node(oid)`. But you can force a given oid, e.g.

```
import oids
import grim

var g = newGrap("my graph")
let myOid: string = $genOid()

let node = g.addNode("F4", %(Id: "none", desc: "OK"), oid=myOid)

echo g.node(myOid)
```

Remember to create a new `oid` for every node / edge you insert, or they would not get inserted:

```
let myoid = "dontdothis"

let node = g.addNode("F4", %(Id: "none", desc: "OK"), oid=myoid)
let dest = g.addNode("F8", %(Id: "dest"), oid=myoid) # Oh, no! Reusing myoid!

echo g
# <Graph "my graph" with 1 node(s) {"F4": 1} and 0 edge(s) {:}>
# Ops! dest node missing
```

Remember that `g.addNode` returns the `oid` corresponding to the inserted Node, so you can always do:

```
echo g.node(node)
echo g.node(dest)
```

The reason for this is that you can insert multiple nodes with the same label, but they are going to get a different `oid`. If you want to extract your nodes by label:

```
for node in g.nodes("F4"):
  echo node
  # Also available
  # node.label
  # node.oid
```

If you are 100% sure your labels are unique, just pass the label as oid:

```
let node = g.addNode("F4", %(Id: "none", desc: "OK"), oid="F4")
echo g.node("F4")
```

Comment: Thank you @xbello, this was exactly what I need as the file I parse is giving me unique ids for each node!
I'm still checking if this library is suitable for my needs (probably), still looks the best candidate in Nim :)